# How to condense pandas rows by query?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a database in Pandas, of stylized form

```
{Value:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],Time:[0,0,0,1,1,1,1],Name:[Rat,Rat,Dog,Rat,Rat,Dog,Cat]}.
```

My goal is to make a dataframe that looks like

```
{Value:[1.5,4.5,3,6,7],Name:[RatT0,RatT1,DogT0,DogT1,CatT1]}.
```

I've looked at `pandas.crosstab`, `pandas.merge`, and `pivot tables`, and none of them provide an obvious way to accomplish this. `groupby` seems promising, but I can't quite figure out how to make it respect the pre-existing boundaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the name column, then `groupby` + `mean`

```
df['Name'] = df.Name + 'T' + df.Time.astype('str')
df.groupby('Name', as_index=False).Value.mean()

    Name  Value
0  CatT1    7.0
1  DogT0    3.0
2  DogT1    6.0
3  RatT0    1.5
4  RatT1    4.5
```

---

For illustration you want to form groups of the same `'Name'` with the same `'Time'`, so you would `groupby` both of these columns and choose what do do with the grouped data (in this case determine a mean of the `'Value'` column). You could then modify the name to be what you want, and remove the redundant `'Time'` column.

```
df = df.groupby(['Name', 'Time'], as_index=False).Value.mean()
#  Name  Time  Value
#0  Cat     1    7.0
#1  Dog     0    3.0
#2  Dog     1    6.0
#3  Rat     0    1.5
#4  Rat     1    4.5

df['Name'] = df.Name + 'T' + df.Time.astype('str')
df.drop(columns='Time', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to do? Just add the 1/0 to your name column?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],'Time':[0,0,0,1,1,1,1],
                   'Name':['Rat','Rat','Dog','Rat','Rat','Dog','Cat']})

df['new_name'] = df['Name'] + 'T' + df['Time'].astype('str')
```